# table function of R confusion

Tags: r, statistics

New to table (in base) in R, confused about what means 0 and 1 in the output. Also in R manual (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/table.html), it is said "uses the cross-classifying factors", tried hard but cannot find a good example, and if anyone could show me what means "uses the cross-classifying factors" by an example, it will be great. Thanks.

```
> a <- letters[1:3]
> 
> a
[1] "a" "b" "c"
> table(a, sample(a))  

a   a b c
  a 1 0 0
  b 0 0 1
  c 0 1 0
> table(a)  
a
a b c 
1 1 1
```

Comment: When you run `table(a,sample(a)` you are inputting two vectors of equal length the first being (a,b,c) and the second being a,b,c in a random order. The table of 1s and 0s indicates the quantity for each pairwise combinations, so you have 1 A,A and 1 B,C and 1 C,B as your combinations between the vector a and sample(a)

Comment: Thanks @Carl, in order to use the table I build, do I have to assign the table to some variable?

Comment: Yes. Also try these examples: `table(a, a)` which produces (more or less) an identity matrix. Also, `table(letters[1:3], rev(letters[1:3]))` which creates a table with the counts in the second diagonal.

Comment: Thanks lmo, and what means "uses the cross-classifying factors"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following as an example

```
> x <- c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,1) 
> y <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,5)
> 
> table(x)  
x
1 2 3 4 
2 2 3 4 
> # x has 2 ones, 2 twos, 2 threes, 4 fours  
> 
> table(y)  
y
1 2 3 4 5 
4 4 1 1 1 
> # y has 4 ones, 4 twos, 1 three, 1 four, 1 five
> 
> table(x,y) 
   y
x   1 2 3 4 5
  1 1 0 0 0 1
  2 1 1 0 0 0
  3 1 2 0 0 0
  4 1 1 1 1 0
> # For example there are 2 cases when x is three and y is two at the same time
> # but 0 cases when x is two and y is three at the same time
```

Comment: Thanks Henry, vote up. And your sample of `table(x,y)` means "uses the cross-classifying factors"? And cross-classifying factor are `x` and `y`? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa I suspect the "factors" (another topic in R) are the values of `x` and `y` and the "cross-classifying" is the table itself

Comment: Thanks Henry, vote up. What do you mean `the values of x and y`? For example, `x=1, y=1` is one factor (similar to combination of any value of `x` and any value of `y`)?

Comment: @LinMa - I suspect `1` is a factor of `x` and similarly `1` is a factor of `y`, and since they happen once together (the first value of `x` and the first value of `y`), `table(x,y)` shows a `1` in the corresponding cell

Comment: Thanks Henry, vote up. What means `factor` here? It seems means a possible value of a variable?

Comment: @LinMa: something like that - it is not particularly relevant to `table` but you could try `?factor` in R for more information about factor encoding

Comment: Thanks for answering my question Henry! Mark your reply as an answer.